# Different versions of De Bello Gallico?

Tags: gaius-iulius-caesar

I seem to have encountered different versions of Caesar's *De Bello Gallico*. For example, in Book I, section 53, one version reads like this:

***...incidit in Caesarem ipsum persequentem equitatem hostium.***

Yet, in a different publication I read this:

***...in ipsum Caesarem hostes equitatu persequentem incidit.***

These two clauses do not mean the same thing. What is going on here? Are there actually different manuscript traditions created in antiquity, or is this a case of a modern editors rewriting Caesar according to their whim? (By "modern" I mean after 1400 AD)

Comment: Can you add which versions these two are? Thanks.

Comment: @cmw The second version is from the Loeb library. I don't know where the first is from because it is in transcribed notes. Does it really matter where they are from? Either there are different manuscript versions, or there are not. What if I didn't even give examples and just asked whether there were substantially different mss traditions?

Comment: It helps the one giving you an answer by pointing them directly to your problem, instead of them guessing where you got information from. Maybe there are different manuscript versions. Knowing for sure would take some investigation. Basically, help us help you get the most accurate information. // But also, perhaps there is some reason you have transcribed notes that don't match the Loeb that have nothing to do with the mss tradition. In that case, we can then further comment and potentially shine light on that problem as well.

Comment: [The Loeb's introduction](https://ryanfb.github.io/loebolus-data/L072.pdf) briefly discusses the manuscript tradition (pp. 26-27 in this public domain one). For a more detailed account and the provenance of any given piece of text you'll have to consult a critical edition.

Answer (score 2):

I eventually figured out the answer to this question.

There was an extensive and varied collection of manuscript variants to all of Caesar's Commentaries and these date back to antiquity, so even in modern texts, wide variations in the text, including even different names of people, are present. In fact, different manuscripts in some cases have different arrangements of volumes or even entirely different volumes that are in some cases considered spurious.

Some classicists have speculated that the Commentaries were unpublished at the time of Caesar's death and this led to a wide variety of his books being issued at the very beginning. Oddly enough, there has been suprisingly little scholarly attention to this manuscript tradition (see Sihler's paper cited below for more about this).

Some of the journal articles discussing the manuscript tradition are "The Cues of Caesar" by Francis Kelsey, The Classical Journal, 1906, and "The tradition of Caesar's Gallic Wars from Cicero to Orosius" by E.G. Sihler, Transactions of the American Philological Association, Vol. 18 (1887), pp. 19-29, and "Caesar's "Commentarii": Writings in Search of a Genre" by Vincent J. Cleary, The Classical Journal, Vol. 80, No. 4 (Apr. - May, 1985), pp. 345-350.